# How to install Django on different version of PYTHON?

Tags: django

I have two python versions 2.6 and 3.0. I want to install django1.3 in python3.0's site-package directory and my default python setting is on 2.6. I also added path /usr/local/bin/python3.0 and /usr/local/bin/python3.0 into .bashrc file.
Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is not compatible with Python 3. You must install it in the 2.X branch.

However, what you want to achive will be easier done using [virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv):

```
easy_install virtualenv
virtualenv project --python=python2.6
source project/bin/activate
pip install django
```

Comment: If you're confused and from the future, like me, then you should know that as of [1.11.17](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11.17/), Django supports Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't yet work with python3.0. So it is better you install it on the python2.6 dist-packages folder.

That said, if you had python2.7 and wanted to install django on python 2.7, while the better approach is to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), a simple solution is to:

```
python2.7 setup.py install
```

or

```
easy_install2.7 django
```

or

```
/path/to/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

```
easy_install virtualenv

pip install django

Sudo pip install django
```

Seemed to work for me!

Answer (score 0):

by using pip install django --> it installs the latest version of django.
https://technicalforum.wordpress.com/2016/12/17/introduction-to-django/