# installing modules into python2.7 when using multiple versions

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have been using python2.6.  I needed to update to python2.7, so I installed it, and now I have both versions of python installed.  I need to know how to install modules like django in python2.7.  I have django installed already for 2.6, but when I try and run python.manage.py on 2.7 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, and I have read on this site that it uses python2.6 by default and it is not a good idea to remove it because the os uses it for certain things.  When I try and re-install django it says the requirement is already met by python2.6.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Django on different version of PYTHON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275393/how-to-install-django-on-different-version-of-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Virtual Python environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) are going to be the best solution. There are a number of good introductions:

- http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
- http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/

In your instance you need to find the path to your Python 2.7 executable.

```
which <whatever you type for python 2.7>
```

Then create a new virtual environment (anywhere you like away from your source code).

```
virtualenv -p </path/to/python/2.7/executable> </your/virtual/env/location>
```

e.g.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/andrew/envs/project_a
```

Then activate the environment and install Django

```
source /home/andrew/envs/project_a/bin/activate
pip install Django
```

You will need to activate the environment before running any Django commands.